# EXTI on GPIOB does not work but on GPIOA everything's ok

Tags: embedded, stm32, microcontroller

I would like to enable EXTI interrupts in order to have information on whether the port has changed its state.
As you can see below, I've configured 2 pins, GPIOA5 and GPIOB3. Both have been configured with pullup resistors, so they should change state when they are connected to the ground.

The problem is that everything works for GPIOA5 but doesn't work for GPIOB3. The isr for GPIO5 is being called, but for GPIOB isn't.

I commented part of code regarding UART configuration as it's not relevant in this case - uart works fine, so I can see messages going out from MCU.

What could be a problem here?

I'm using STM32f411CEU6 and libopencm3.

```
#include <libopencm3/stm32/gpio.h>

#include <libopencm3/stm32/flash.h>
#include <libopencm3/cm3/systick.h>

volatile bool sensor_isr_process { false };
volatile bool sensor_isr_process2 { false };

extern "C" {

void exti3_isr()
{
  sensor_isr_process2 = true;

    exti_reset_request(EXTI3);
}

void exti9_5_isr()
{
  sensor_isr_process = true;

    exti_reset_request(EXTI5);
}
}

void configure_exti(uint32_t nvicirq, uint32_t exti, uint32_t gpioport)
{
  nvic_enable_irq(nvicirq);

  exti_select_source(exti, gpioport);

  exti_set_trigger(exti, EXTI_TRIGGER_FALLING);
  exti_enable_request(exti);
}

int main()
{
  //Setup Clock
  auto clock = rcc_clock_scale{};
  clock.pllm = 8;
  clock.plln = 100; //336;
  clock.pllp = 2; //4;
  clock.pllq = 4; //7;
  clock.pllr = 2; //0;
  clock.pll_source = RCC_CFGR_PLLSRC_HSI_CLK;
  clock.hpre = RCC_CFGR_HPRE_DIV_NONE; //?
  clock.ppre1 = RCC_CFGR_PPRE_DIV_2; // ?
  clock.ppre2 = RCC_CFGR_PPRE_DIV_NONE; // ?
  clock.voltage_scale = PWR_SCALE1; //?
  clock.flash_config = FLASH_ACR_DCEN | FLASH_ACR_ICEN |
      FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_2WS;
  clock.ahb_frequency  = 100000000;
  clock.apb1_frequency = 50000000;
  clock.apb2_frequency = 100000000;

  rcc_clock_setup_pll(&clock);

  //Enable GPIO
  rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_GPIOA);
  rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_GPIOB);

  //Setup GPIO
  gpio_mode_setup(GPIOA, GPIO_MODE_INPUT, GPIO_PUPD_PULLUP, GPIO5);
  gpio_mode_setup(GPIOB, GPIO_MODE_INPUT, GPIO_PUPD_PULLUP, GPIO3);

  configure_exti(NVIC_EXTI9_5_IRQ, EXTI5, GPIOA);
  configure_exti(NVIC_EXTI3_IRQ,   EXTI3, GPIOB);

  while(1)
  {
    if (sensor_isr_process) {
      // trace(1, "Sensor 1\r\n"); //sends message by uart
      sensor_isr_process = false;
    } 
    else if (sensor_isr_process2) {
      // trace(1, "Sensor 2\r\n"); //send message by uart
      sensor_isr_process2 = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Datasheet says PB3 is used for SWO :) So maybe something is clashing? Try changing the alternate function for the pin, I guess you can live with SWO unless you really need it for debugging. https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f411ce.pdf

Comment: Come to think of it, you might need a completely different pin, if I remember correct the pins default to AF0. And that pin can't be used for "GPIO", correct me if I'm wrong here.

Comment: I checked with PA1 and for this pin it works, on the other hand, I also checked for PB4, PB12, and for these ports, nothing happens.

Comment: Pb4 is jrst by default, pb12 should work though.. strange.. have you checked GPIOB register contents, against the datasheets reset values ? And try to write GPIOBs ODR for pin 12 and check with an oscilloscope that it does indeed work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with *libopencm3*, but normally EXTI mappings are configured in **SYSCFG_EXTICR** registers and in order to access them, **SYSCFG** clock needs to be enabled.

If you inspect its [source](http://libopencm3.org/docs/latest/stm32f4/html/exti__common__all_8c_source.html#l00112) file, you can see that `exti_select_source()` function doesn't enable **SYSCFG** clock itself. So probably you need to do it yourself by calling the relevant function:

```
rcc_periph_clock_enable(RCC_SYSCFG);
```

Comment: You're right. I added this line and it has just started working. I will do some more tests and then if it works I will accept your answer. Thanks!